# Semantic UI message list does not shows correctly

Tags: css, semantic-ui

Here is my code

```
<div class="ui info message">
    <i class="close icon"></i>
    <div class="header">
        Was this what you wanted?
    </div>
    <ul class="list">
        <li>It's good to see you again.</li>
        <li>Did you know it's been a while?</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In my browser both chrome and Mozilla shows this output

[image]

But in jsfiddle worked correctly.

http://jsfiddle.net/06rmnLLv/

How to fix this.

Comment: Copy back the jsfiddle code in your page and see if it works.! It seems everything fine in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this character `'`. You can replace it with HTML entities (`&grave;`)

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/06rmnLLv/2/)

Comment: In stack it show correctly but prblem still in my browser

Comment: @russell try to change encoding of your browser.

Comment: @russell what is your browser version?

Comment: Solved. changing encoding. Mozilla: 41.0.2

Comment: @russell Okay, great.